# Multi slides carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Hi guys I need bit help in extending functionality of a multi-slide JS carousel.

- User click on next button then item#1 got hidden and item 2,3,4,5,6 should display.
- Again user click on next then Item#1 and 2 got hide and 3,4,5,6,7 should display
- should hide the button on last item
- Inverse the case for previous button.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('ul li:gt(4)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(5)').show();
    first.prev().nextAll().hide();
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(5)').show();
    last.next().prevAll().hide();
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
</ul>
<a class="prev">prev</a> | <a class="next">next</a>
```

A javascript fiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/90faL0c1

Comment: Include source code, link js fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/90faL0c1/1/

Changed function to these to hide and show the appropriate numbers:

```
$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first'),
    last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');

    if(first.prev().length > 0){
       last.hide();
       first.prev().show();
    }


});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first'),
    last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');

    if(last.next().length > 0){
       first.hide();
       last.next().show();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can we hide the next prev button if we reach at last item.

Comment: Fairly easy, you just manipulate the if statements a little. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/90faL0c1/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code
replace on prev function

```
var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
```

to

```
var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
```

and replace on next function

```
var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
```

to

```
var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bit closer to the question.